# how to import the application Context?

Tags: java, spring

i have installed the STS tool through eclipse Marketplace and created a java project . While writing the code, it's not showing to import the library for application context .

Also i have added the external library and configured the buildPath, but no results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ApplicationContext appCon=new 
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("StudentConfig.xml"); 

    StudentBean factory=(StudentBean)appCon.getBean("studentbean"); 
    factory.displayInfo(); 

}
```

Where am i doing wrong??

[image: Program Structure]

Comment: You miss the import statements and of cause the related libraries in the class path

Comment: Like Jens said, the libraries itself are not included into the STS. You have to add them seperately.

Comment: hi, i meant that previously when i put my pointer over the redliines, then those library are automatically shown and i have to just click them. but right now  no options are coming.. that means some mistake are there..right??

Comment: if i am installing the sts tool in marketplace, do i need to add the external library(jar files)  again???

Comment: Seem like you miss to include some spring libraries for your project. You should show us what you have  imported so far .Btw. it is already 2019. Highly recommend you to use some build tool (e.g Maven) to include the library rather than include by yourself manually if you want to be a professional Java engineer....

Comment: actually i am new to this. can you tell me how to do that??

Comment: Ok ,mouse over those errors , click `Ctrl+1` to see if it suggests you to import a class . If yes , choose import them . Otherwise , you are missing to import some spring libraries and show us what libraries are you importing so far.

Comment: nope, i am missing some libraries..i guess. this is the path "C:\Users\Debasis.Panda\Downloads\sts-4.1.0.RELEASE\plugins" and i have slected the jar files and added them to the project as a user library. previously it had worked , but now it;s not.

Comment: can anyone reply over this??if i am installing the sts tool in marketplace, do i need to add the external library(jar files) again??? – DEBASIS PANDA 58 mins ago

Comment: Yes, you need to install the required jars. Seems that you are don't know the basics. Usually maven or gradle is used to import the required jars. STS is for the IDE, not for the program itself. I recommend to learn more basics before starting programming with spring. Spring is pretty difficult to learn if you don't know them.

Comment: ok..i need to add maven to include the jars right??

Answer (score 0):

Check for dependencies depending on whether its maven or gradle. then rebuild your code to show suitable import suggestions